# .htaccess RewriteRule not working in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I'm programming the new version of my website and I'm trying to get .htaccess to rewrite properly. My new site is stored here:

```
www.example.com/storage/new/
```

I need to rewrite these URLs:

```
www.example.com/storage/new/welcome/   -> index.php?action=welcome
www.example.com/storage/new/page/name/ -> index.php?action=page&url=name
www.example.com/storage/new/post/name/ -> index.php?action=post&url=name
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/welcome/$ index.php?action=welcome [L]
RewriteRule ^/page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?action=page&url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/post/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?action=post&url=$1 [L]
```

It does not work, however; all results in a 404 Not Found. I've tried everything, even typing out `www.example.com/storage/new/` in lieu of `^`. I have another .htaccess in the server root (`www.example.com`) that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I can't imagine how that would affect `www.example.com/storage/new/` but you never know. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to e-mail my server's administrator for help and it turns out that .htaccess treats its own path as root; I simply removed the first `/` before the `^` in each rule. My final .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^welcome/$ index.php?action=welcome [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/$ index.php?action=page&url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/$ index.php?action=post&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

The ^ means the start of the string.  The RewriteRules will look at everything after example.com/ so you need to include storage/new/ in your pattern (or remove the ^).

Also I'd probably want to add the NC flag so your pattern is matched without regards to case sensitivity (e.g. /Page/ or /page/ will both work).  Which means you can change the [a-zA-Z0-9] pattern to just [a-z0-9]

```
RewriteRule ^storage/new/welcome/$ index.php?action=welcome [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/new/page/([a-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?action=page&url=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/new/post/([a-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?action=post&url=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, although it still does not work. I've tried everything I can think of and read more tutorials than I can count. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: ok, try adding a rewrite and make sure you end up on the URL you're expecting: RewriteRule ^storage/new/welcome/$ index.php?action=welcome [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Still nothing. There is definitely something else wrong. I'll file a support ticket. Thanks for all your help!