# Deploy modular zend project on a sub-directory host

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, php, web-deployment-project, subdirectory

I am deploying a zend project `myproject` from a local host to a sub-directory www.subdirectory.com/~username/`myproject`, i am facing many problems even though i have read that there is no so much to change to when deploying zend project from local host to sub directory i have tried [this](http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html)  which i took from an answer but it didn't work.

The problem is when I put the link above a file tree with the directory of the project opens, and when I click on public it redirect me to the index page of the default module. and I cant go to any other page

I have no control on the apache2 server. is there a way to deploy the project and this is my code below for the `.htaccess`,`index.php`, and `application.ini` any answers or guidance will be helpful

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

index.php

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define path to application directory
defined('PUBLIC_PATH')
        || define('PUBLIC_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));


// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
        || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));


$paths = array(realpath(dirname(_FILE_) . '/../library'), '.');
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
/* Define the base URL */
define('URL_ADDRESS', "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);


/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
                APPLICATION_ENV,
                APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

Application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1    
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view[] =
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.layout.layout = default    
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =    
autoloaderNamespaces.Hyderlib = "Hyderlib_"
resources.layout.pluginClass= "Hyderlib_Controller_Plugin_ModuleLayout"
resources.view[] = 

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1


resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "password"
resources.db.params.username = "password"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "password"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: [.htaccess RewriteRule not working in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494921/htaccess-rewriterule-not-working-in-subdirectory?rq=1)

I suspect you have to edit the .htaccess to forward requests other than image/css/js through index.php which is not located in the same directory.

If the webserver root is ~/username/ then put .htaccess in there and change

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ myproject/index.php [NC,L]
```

More changes may need to be made to handle the static content (other rewrites).

Comment: Thank you lucian303 This still didn't help, the problem seem if any request is to any page (excepts to the `/default/index` page), the request doesn't reach index.php file in the public.

Comment: No worries. Have you tried using apache's RewriteBase directive? See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase