# htaccess - allow multiple domain origins, force https, force www, rewrite url with subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I would like to create an .htaccess to

1. allow origin (https://www.example.com and https://example.com and https://subdomain.example.com)
2. force https
3. force www
4. rewrite url with the subdirectory

---

**Edit:** Here is my new .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine on

    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com, https://example.com, https://subdomain.example.com"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, X-CSRF-Token"

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteRule ^(path/to/directory/file)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?u=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com, https://example.com, https://subdomain.example.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, X-CSRF-Token"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301]


RewriteRule ^path/to/directory/file/([^/]*)$ path/to/directory/file.php?u=$1 [L]
```

- This rule is **working**: (http://example.com/file/xxxx)

  ```
  RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ path/to/directory/file.php?u=$1 [L]
  ```
- **Edit**: This rule is **working**
  (http://example.com/path/to/directory/file/xxxx)

  ```
  RewriteRule ^path/to/directory/file/([^/]*)$ path/to/directory/file.php?u=$1 [L]
  ```

**Edit**:

Think to remove the first slash after ^ to make it working as said [in this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494921/htaccess-rewriterule-not-working-in-subdirectory).

Comment: The only difference I see is the first rule starting *without* slash and the second one starting *with* slash.

Comment: I did an edit. It's not changing something (I tested the second with and without and it works). To be more clear I removed the second.

Comment: @anubhava I am sorry I did not understand your question. xxxx represent the value of the **u** var. It's the id of an user.

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess in your system or any other rule?

Comment: Right. Thank you! There was a bad .htaccess located on the path/to/directory with bad remaining lines. I removed it and the subdirectory problem is solved. I tested the other rules it's still possible to go on : [https://example.com/](https://example.com/)

Comment: So what part is not working now?

Comment: With my code above, `http://www.example.com, http://example.com and https://www.example.com are redirected to https://www.example.com but not https://example.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all of your existing code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com, https://example.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, X-CSRF-Token"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^(path/to/directory/file)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?u=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thank you all is working perfectly: allow 2 origins, force https, force www, redirection with subdirectory. :)

Comment: A last question, if you would like, if I want to add successive rewriting rules like this one `RewriteRule ^(path/to/directory/file)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?u=$2 [NC,L,QSA]` in order to have several friendly urls, should I just keep the same flags?

Comment: Hi, loading fontawesome icons from a subdomain is generating this error how can I solve this please? `Font from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://www.example.com, https://example.com', https://subdomain.example.com' but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://subdomain.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Yes, also the subdomain directory is located on the /home/sitename directory and the htaccess is located on /home/sitename/public_html directory in order to prevent it from www redirection. But I have still problem with Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the subdomain.

Comment: I think I should have an .htaccess for the directory of the subdomain file. Focing without www and forcing with https. - Edit, ok done through the cPanel redirections. However I'm still stuck with allow origin header it's like it doesn't work

Comment: It's rightly `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the .htaccess of example.com. I've edited the .htaccess above the thread to show you how it is.

Comment: Then it works the subdomain is allowed. However I'd like to be sure to allow the 3 ones.

Comment: You can add 2 more lines of `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Hi it doesn't work then I've an allow origin problem again. `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://subdomain.example.com"`

Comment: [Check this answer for multiple original domains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/548225)

Answer (score 1):

Allow Origin:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Force HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Force WWW:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

URL to subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example [L]
```

Comment: Thank you there is no more problem with www and https redirection. Is it possible to add only `https://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` in the allowed origins? And I don't really understand the URL to subdomain part.