# Maintain separate .htaccess files in sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I maintain 2 separate .htaccess files so as to avoid dumping rules in the main .htaccess file.

For example: I want all the urls trailing after ^shows(/.*)?$ to point to .htaccess created under controllers/shows (.htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your rewrite rules, this can be accomplished with minimal rewriting (heh) of the `.htaccess` file. Take for example this `.htaccess` file stored in the webroot `/var/www/html`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/foo/help/(.*)? /foo/help.php?q=$1
Rewriterule ^blog/(.*)? blog/index.php?id=$1
```

We're doing two kinds of rewrite here:

- `www.example.com/foo/help/123 -> wwww.example.com/foo/help.php?q=123`
- `www.example.com/blog/myarticle -> www.example.com/blog/index.php?id=myarticle`

Notice the first `RewriteRule` is using absolute paths, while the second is using a relative path.

If I were to move the first `RewriteRule` into `/var/www/html/foo/.htaccess`, the file would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/foo/help/(.*)? /foo/help.php?q=$1
```

Note that nothing needs to change, since you're using an absolute path.

Now if I were to move the second `RewriteRule` into `/var/www/html/blog/.htaccess`, the file would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?id=$1
```

Note the paths in the `RewriteRule` were stripped to make them relative to the current directory, which is now `/blog`. Also note the [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive, which is necessary when using relative rewrite rules in a subdirectory.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5494921/4087397) for another example of using subdirectory `.htaccess` rewrite rules.